# html input text with index label

Tags: jquery, html

I need an input text field to enter 17 characters, that input field contains 17 cells each cell contains one character, the label of cell is its index. When user type a character in a cell the next cell take focus automatically and use can go to the previous cell using shortcut key like (shift + tab) or arrow keys.

[the following picture describes my field but with 5 cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1cRd.png)

Comment: So what is your question and what have you tried? The objective here is for you to show us your attempts to solve your issue and people help you with your code when it doesn't work as expected. It is not a free code writing service

Comment: I want a library that has this feature (jquery library for example)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a change event listener in each text field and use jquery/js to focus on the next one by adding +1 to the selector (considering the name of the field will also be formed based on its index). It would be something like:

```html
<style>
  input {
    width: 10px;
  }
</style>

<input maxlength="1" name="0" class="cell">
<input maxlength="1" name="1" class="cell">
<input maxlength="1" name="2" class="cell">

<script>
  let cells = document.getElementsByClassName('cell');
  for (i = 0; i < cells.length; i++)
  {
   cells[i].tabIndex = '-1'; cells[i].addEventListener('keydown', function(e)
    {
      let name = this.name;
      let nextInput = document.getElementsByName(parseInt(name)+1);
      console.log(name);
      if (nextInput[0]) {
          nextInput[0].focus();
      }
    });
  }
  cells[0].focus()
</script>
```